What is the measure of the set of values $S=\{0.x_1x_2... \in (0,1)$ (in binary) for which $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{x_n}}{n}$ converges$\}$?
I think the measure is zero but I'm not sure. I'm pretty sure the set is measurable because its construction does not require Axiom of Choice. I don't know where to begin.
Edit: It was shown to be 1 by Kolmogorov's three series theorem.
A further question: Consider the function $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ mapping $x$ values to the value of the corresponding series, and to $0$ otherwise. This function maps every open set to the whole real line. Does it map every set of positive measure to the whole real line?

With regard to which measure? For the trivial measure it has measure 0 and for the counting measure it has infinity. You probably mean with respect to the Lebesque measure, right?

It has measure $1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Random_harmonic_series

@DavidGao Thank you! I have updated the question with another query that I had. Can you help me with this one also?

The answer to your further question is no for kinda the same reason as your other question: either $\mu(f\geq 0)$ or $\mu(f<0)$ is strictly positive.

@Adam As Jonathan mentioned, the answer is no. In fact, as the series converges a.s., $\mu(f \geq 0) = \mu(f < 0) = 1/2$, so in particular the set of numbers $x$ for which $f(x) \geq 0$ is a positive measure set that is mapped by $f$ only to the positive half of the real line.

@JonathanHole How do we know ${x: f(x)\geq 0}$ and ${x:f(x)<0}$ are even measurable?

@Adam Heuristically, as you said, the construction never uses the axiom of choice, so it has to be measurable. Rigorously, the partial sum $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{x_n}}{n}$ up to the $k$-th term is clearly measurable. Now, $f(x) \geq 0$ is the same as saying for all $n > 0$, there exists $m > 0$, s.t. for all $k \geq m$, $S_k < 1/n$. So ${x: f(x) \geq 0}$ is a countable intersection of countable unions of countable intersections of measurable sets, whence measurable itself. ${x: f(x) < 0}$ is its complement, so it’s also measurable.

I see, but is it not possible to construct a non-measurable function mapping every set of positive measure to the whole real line without using the axiom of choice? The existence of non-principal ultrafilters is strictly weaker than Axiom of Choice, but it implies the existence of non-measurable sets.

@Adam I mean, such a function is necessarily non-measurable, per the same reason as in Jonathan’s comment, so some axiom of choice is necessary at some point. Does such a function even exist though? If it does (under the axiom of choice), I doubt you need the full axiom of choice to prove that. But I can’t see how to construct it in the first place.

@DavidGao How about the following: Take any function $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ that maps any open interval in $\mathbb{Q}$ to the whole of $\mathbb{Q}$. Choose $r_\theta$, representatives of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ using Ax of Choice. Extend this $f$ to a function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by letting $F(\theta)=f(\theta - r_\theta) + r_\theta$.

@Adam This won’t work. Fix any $\theta$. Then $\mathbb{R} \setminus (r_\theta + \mathbb{Q})$ is of positive (indeed, infinite) measure, but it’s mapped onto itself, not the entire $\mathbb{R}$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The OP’s main question has already been resolved in the comments. The following is a long comment addressing OP’s follow-up question in comments, namely, we show that under AC, we can construct a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(A) = \mathbb{R}$ for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with positive measure.
Let $\mathfrak{c}$ be the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $(r_\lambda)_{\lambda < \mathfrak{c}}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{R}$ in which every element appears $\mathfrak{c}$ many times. (This can be arranged, for example, by fixing a bijection $\iota: \mathfrak{c} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and let $r_\lambda$ be the first coordinate of $\iota(\lambda)$.) Recall that the collection of all Borel sets has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, so the same holds for the collection of all Borel sets with positive measure. Let $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda < \mathfrak{c}}$ be an enumeration of such sets.
We now construct, through transfinite induction, a function $f_\lambda$ for each $\lambda < \mathfrak{c}$ s.t., for each $\lambda$, $f_\lambda$ is a function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality smaller than or equal to $\max\{\aleph_0, |\lambda|\}$, and has codomain $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $f_\lambda \subset f_\kappa$ whenever $\lambda \leq \kappa < \mathfrak{c}$.
Assume for some $\lambda < \mathfrak{c}$, all $f_\kappa$ for $\kappa < \lambda$ have been constructed. We observe that $\cup_{\kappa < \lambda} f_\kappa$ is a function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with cardinality smaller than or equal to $\max\{\aleph_0, |\lambda|\} < \mathfrak{c}$. Recall that any Borel set of positive measure must have cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, whence we may choose (by another transfinite induction), $x_{\lambda, \eta} \in A_\eta$ for each $\eta \leq \lambda$, s.t. $x_{\lambda, \eta_1} \neq x_{\lambda, \eta_2}$ for any $\eta_1 \neq \eta_2$ and $x_{\lambda, \eta} \notin \text{dom}(\cup_{\kappa < \lambda} f_\kappa)$. Let,
$$f_\lambda = (\bigcup_{\kappa < \lambda} f_\kappa) \cup \{(x_{\lambda, \eta}, r_\lambda): \eta \leq \lambda\}$$
Now, having finished the inductive construction, we note that $\cup_{\lambda < \mathfrak{c}} f_\lambda$ is a partially defined function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Extend it arbitrarily to a fully defined function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. We claim that $f$ satisfies the requisite property. Indeed, for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ of positive measure, it must contain a Borel set of positive measure as a subset, say, $A_\eta \subset A$ for some $\eta < \mathfrak{c}$. Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Since each real number appears in the enumeration $(r_\lambda)_{\lambda < \mathfrak{c}}$ $\mathfrak{c}$ many times, there exists $\kappa \geq \eta$ s.t. $r_\kappa = r$. But then by definition of $f_\kappa$, we see that $x_{\kappa, \eta} \in A_\eta$ and,
$$f(x_{\kappa, \eta}) = f_\kappa(x_{\kappa, \eta}) = r_\kappa = r$$
So $r \in f(A_\eta) \subset f(A)$. Since $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, this shows $f(A) = \mathbb{R}$.
Remark 1: The construction of such an $f$ necessarily depends on some AC. Indeed, any such $f$ satisfies the following strong non-measurability property: for any $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ that is neither empty nor the entire $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(K)$ cannot be measurable, regardless of whether $K$ is measurable or not. Indeed, if $f^{-1}(K)$ were to be measurable, then so is $\mathbb{R} \setminus f^{-1}(K) = f^{—1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus K)$. Thus, either $f^{-1}(K)$ or $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus K)$ has to have positive measure, contradicting the assumption on $f$. However, if I’m not mistaken, the above proof only used AC to the extent that $\mathbb{R}$ is well-orderable. That is definitely far weaker than the full AC.
Remark 2: The above proof shows that, given any collection $\Sigma$ of at most $\mathfrak{c}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, each of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, one may construct an $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(A) = \mathbb{R}$ for all $A \in \Sigma$. Note that this stands in contrast to the case where we require $f(A) = \mathbb{R}$ for all $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, which is impossible to arrange, as has been demonstrated in this answer to another question of the OP’s.
